# Samsung phone custom setting style

Tags: android

I have a  custom setting style, which runs well on the HTC, iphone but on the Samsung phone I get erros like: `ERROR/AndroidRuntime(726): java.lang.RuntimeException: Binary XML file line #18: You must supply a layout_width attribute`.

my xml:

```
<style name="PreferencesTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Light">
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/screen_background_light</item>
  <item name="android:listSeparatorTextViewStyle">@style/ListSeparator</item>
   <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
  <item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item>
   <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
</style>
```

my style:

```
    <activity android:name=".Setting.MainSettingActivity"   
              android:theme="@style/PreferencesTheme"    
               android:screenOrientation="portrait" ></activity>
```

this generates an error.so i modified my code. I  added this code :

```
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    setTheme(R.style.PreferencesTheme);
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preferences);......
```

but still have same error. The activity is a SettingActivity, but on the htc iphone it is working correctly.

Comment: Now that the DDMS tells you "Binary XML file line #18: You must supply a layout_width attribute. "; I think you might as well check that line(error occurs in #18, so it has nothing to do with the style XML). Perhaps you need something like 'android:layout_width="wrap_content" '

Answer (score 1):

Add:

```
<item name="android:layout_width">match_parent</item>
<item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
```

To your custom TextView.ListSeparator style.